# Got error movenext on SOOrder Type SO after convert from QT and delete SO

Tags: customization, acumatica

I use this below coding to customize the RequestDate on Document Detail (SOOrder screen: Type QT) but it got error after I converted that QT to SO and delete that SO.

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
{ 
  var order = Base.Document.Current;
  if(order.OrderType == "QT" )
  {
    order.RequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate ;//Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
    foreach(SOLine so in Base.Transactions.Select())
    {
      so.RequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
      Base.Transactions.Update(so); 
    }
  } 
  baseMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add validation for status of your SOOrder before updating RequestDate for SOOrder and each SOLine:

```
if (Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(order) != PXEntryStatus.InsertedDeleted || Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(order) != PXEntryStatus.Deleted)
{
    if(order.OrderType == "QT" )
    {
        order.RequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
        foreach(SOLine so in Base.Transactions.Select())
        {
            so.RequestDate = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
            Base.Transactions.Update(so); 
        }
    } 
}
```